# Android Application session Management?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm Developing the android app based on the session management, I'm using the app normally like move forward and backward, on the time if some make a call or the user to tap the home key in android device that time the app runs background that means stopped but not destroyed, After 15 minutes I'm going to open again in the particular app that time your session is invalid please login like alert show and page directly goto  login page, Which one is best way of handling the background process. Could you update the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Service in background with a Timer, and set that timer to 15 min. When user resume the app before 15 min then stop the timer and show main screen and if timer is over land them to login screen.

Simple :)